# Gremlin Distance matrix with multiple edge properties of a path

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I'm new to gremlin, please help me with a query for below graph data.

Gremlin sample graph

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
v1 = g.addV('4630').property('loc','B_1_1').next()
v2 = g.addV('4630').property('loc','C_1_1').next()
e1 = g.addE('sp').from(v1).to(v2).property('dist',1).property('anglein',90).property('angleout',45).next()
e2 = g.addE('sp').from(v2).to(v1).property('dist',2).property('anglein',190).property('angleout',145)
```

Expected result:

```
source destination dist angein angleout
B_1_1  C_1_1       1    90     145
C_1_1  B_1_1       2    190    145
```

Query that I'm trying is:

```
g.V().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
  outE('sp').
  inV().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
  path().
    by('loc').
    by(valueMap().select(values)).
    by('loc')
```

With below result

```
==>[B_1_1,[90,1,45],C_1_1]
==>[C_1_1,[190,2,145],B_1_1]
```

Want to have all the path edge properties in the result without any inner result. Please help how can I achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to flatten your result.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
......1>   outE('sp').
......2>   inV().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
......3>   path().
......4>     by('loc').
......5>     by(valueMap().select(values)).
......6>     by('loc').
......7>   map(unfold().unfold().fold())
==>[B_1_1,90,1,45,C_1_1]
==>[C_1_1,190,2,145,B_1_1]
```

Each path will need to be flattened so you want to apply that operation with `map()`. To flatten you need to first `unfold()` the path and then `unfold()` each item in the path. Since the `map()` operation will only `next()` that child traversal you need to include a final `fold()` to convert that flattened stream of objects back to a `List`.

Comment: Thanks @stephen. It worked, what is the performance impact  if I fetch half a million rows with this query?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Stephen already said, you could also get rid of the `by()` modulation in your path step and instead use the path elements to collect all the values you need afterward. This will save you a few traversers and thus it should be slightly faster.

```
g.V().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
  outE('sp').inV().has('4630','loc',within('B_1_1','C_1_1')).
  path().
  map(unfold().values('loc','dist','anglein','angleout').fold())
```

Also, note that even if you prefer the other query, you shouldn't use `valueMap`. `valueMap().select(values)` is just a waste of resources in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. It worked, what is the performance impact  if I fetch half a million rows with this query?

Comment: It's pretty bad I would say. OLTP graph queries shouldn't fetch that much data, unless you really don't care about long response times.

Comment: My requirement is, I have a fully connected graph and I want to fetch the distance matrix by using the query you mentioned. What is the best way to achieve it? Graph will contains around 2000 nodes which fully connected and at any point of time I want to fetch a matrix of 500X500 nodes distance data.